# Php Query about XAMPP

Tags: php

I have created a PHP file as avnish.php in htdocs folder of XAMPP.
But while i am executing this file on local host as "localhost/avnish.php" in my browser, my browser searching on Google.

Kindly help me out regarding this.

Comment: Try `http://localhost/avnish.php`.

Comment: Or try another browser to see the result.

Comment: Your server is not running , run it first

Answer (score 0):

You should write full text:

```
http://localhost/avnish.php
```

Some browsers recognize it as keyword for search. Try the above example. and if the problem still exists use another browser.